# Specify alternative line_end character for Elixir File.stream! function

Tags: file, filestream, elixir

Elixir's `File.stream!` splits on and assumed `\r` character.

Is it possible to specify for example, `\r\n` or any other pattern?

Such a convenience would make `File.stream!` a handy file parser.

**Edit: Added source file content:**

```
 iex(1)> File.read! "D:\\Projects\\Telegram\\PQ.txt"
"1039027537039357001\r\n1124138842463513719\r\n1137145765766942221\r\n1159807134726147157\r\n1162386423249503807\r\n1166092057686212149\r\n1192934946182607263\r\n1239437837009623463\r\n1242249431735251217\r\n1286092661601003031\r\n1300223652350017207\r\n1320700236992142661\r\n1322986082402655259\r\n1342729635050601557\r\n1342815051384338027\r\n1361578683715077199\r\n1381265403472415423\r\n1387654405700676857\r\n1414719090657425471\r\n1438176310698548801\r\n1440426998028857687\r\n1444777794598883737\r\n1448786004429696643\r\n1449069084476072141\r\n1449922801627060913\r\n1459186197300152561\r\n1470497644058466497\r\n1497532721434112879\r\n1514370843858307907\r\n1528087672407582373\r\n1530255914631110911\r\n1537681216742780453\r\n1547498566041252091\r\n1563354550428106363\r\n1570520040759209689\r\n1570650619548126013\r\n1572342415580617699\r\n1595238677050713949\r\n1602246062455069687\r\n1603930707387709439\r\n1620038771342153713\r\n1626781435762382063\r\n1628817368590631491\r\n1646011824126204499\r\n1654346190847567153\r\n1671293643237388043\r\n1674249379765115707\r\n1683876665120978837\r\n1700490364729897369\r\n1724114033281923457\r\n1729626235343064671\r\n1736390408379387421\r\n1742094280210984849\r\n1750652888783086363\r\n1756848379834132853\r\n1769689620230136307\r\n1791811376213642701\r\n1802412521744570741\r\n1816018323888992941\r\n1816202297040826291\r\n1833488086890603497\r\n1834281595607491843\r\n1840295490995033057\r\n1843931859412695937\r\n1845134226412607369\r\n1847514467055999659\r\n1868936961235125427\r\n18733753
```

Example:

```
iex(134)> s|> Enum.to_list

["1039027537039357001\n", "1124138842463513719\n", "1137145765766942221\n",
 "1159807134726147157\n", "1162386423249503807\n", "1166092057686212149\n",
 "1192934946182607263\n", "1239437837009623463\n", "1242249431735251217\n",
 "1286092661601003031\n", "1300223652350017207\n", "1320700236992142661\n",
 "1322986082402655259\n", "1342729635050601557\n", "1342815051384338027\n",
 "1361578683715077199\n", "1381265403472415423\n", "1387654405700676857\n",
 "1414719090657425471\n", "1438176310698548801\n", "1440426998028857687\n",
 "1444777794598883737\n", "1448786004429696643\n", "1449069084476072141\n",
 "1449922801627060913\n", "1459186197300152561\n", "1470497644058466497\n",
 "1497532721434112879\n", "1514370843858307907\n", "1528087672407582373\n",
 "1530255914631110911\n", "1537681216742780453\n", "1547498566041252091\n",
 "1563354550428106363\n", "1570520040759209689\n", "1570650619548126013\n",
 "1572342415580617699\n", "1595238677050713949\n", "1602246062455069687\n",
 "1603930707387709439\n", "1620038771342153713\n", "1626781435762382063\n",
 "1628817368590631491\n", "1646011824126204499\n", "1654346190847567153\n",
 "1671293643237388043\n", "1674249379765115707\n", "1683876665120978837\n",
 "1700490364729897369\n", "1724114033281923457\n", ...]

iex(135)> s|> String.to_integer|> Primes.factorize|> Enum.to_list
```

Comment: Elixir already works with \n and \r\n transparently. I don't see why one would want to specify the line breaks in this case. Can you please paste exactly which output you are getting and let us know which output you were expecting?

Comment: @JoséValim I have updated to include source file content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir handles the differences between Windows and Unix just fine by always normalizing "\r\n" into "\n", so developers don't need to worry about both formats. That's what is happening in the example above and that's what you should expect from the operations in both IO and File module.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file in raw mode (see [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/File.html#stream!/3)) and check the characters yourself.

Comment: `by :line (default) or by a given number of bytes` does not say how to specify a split option the way :line does

Comment: If we could define what `:line` option is then that would be very flexible

Comment: You would use the "number of bytes"  and scan for the \n manually.

Comment: Got it. But you can see how being able to **simply specify what :line actually is** would make parsing the very common example of files with the default windows `\r\n` breaks

Comment: Given that Elixir started on Macs and Linux the issue of the line break isn't terribly surprising.  I think you should submit a PR to allow the line break to be picked up from the platform.  No joke.